# How to sort and filter an array of objects in Vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to both filter and sort an array of objects in Vue. Currently I am filtering the array, but I would like to add a sort feature. I have created a dropdown component and used the Event Bus to send the result of the clicked dropdown item to the component I would like to do the sorting.

However, I am unsure on how to show BOTH filter and sort options.

**My component that renders the array of objects and filters/ sorts it**

```
<template>
  <div class="cards">
    <CountdownCard
      v-for="(event, index) in filteredItems"
      :key="index"
      :event="event"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CountdownCard from '@/components/CountdownCard'
import EventBus from '@/components/EventBus'

export default {
  components: {
    CountdownCard
  },
  data() {
    return {
      events: [
        {
          title: 'Christmas',
          date: 'December 25, 2020',
          emoji: '',
          type: 'holiday',
          year: 2020,
          month: 11,
          day: 21,
          hour: 0,
          minute: 0
        },
        {
          title: 'Spring',
          date: 'March 21, 2020',
          emoji: '',
          type: 'season',
          year: 2021,
          month: 2,
          day: 21,
          hour: 0,
          minute: 0
        },
        {
          title: "Tyler's Birthday",
          date: 'September 14, 2020',
          emoji: '',
          type: 'custom',
          year: 2020,
          month: 8,
          day: 14,
          hour: 0,
          minute: 0
        }
      filter: '',
      sort: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    return (
      EventBus.$on('filter-catagories', filter => {
        this.filter = filter
      }),
      EventBus.$on('sort-catagories', sort => {
        this.sort = sort
      })
    )
  },
  computed: {
    filteredItems: function() {
      // filters at work
      return (
        this.events
          // search filter
          .filter(event => {
            return event.title
              .toLowerCase()
              .includes(this.updateSearch.toLowerCase())
          })
          // category filters
          .filter(event => {
            if (this.filter == '' || this.filter == 'all') {
              return this.events
            } else {
              return event.type == this.filter
            }
          })
      )
    },
    sortedItems: function:{
        // logic for sorting
  }
}
</script>
```

**Here is my component for the dropdown**

```
<template>
  <div class="dropDownContainer">
    <div class="selection" :class="{ opened: opened }" @click="toggle">
      <span class="selectionText">
        {{ selected.label }}
        <span class="downArrow"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <transition name="grow">
      <div class="options" v-if="opened">
        <span
          v-for="(option, index) in choices"
          :key="index"
          @click="makeSelection(option), emitSort(option.name)"
        >
          {{ option.label }}
        </span>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import EventBus from '@/components/EventBus'

export default {
  props: {
    choices: Array,
    menuLabel: String
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      selected: this.choices[0],
      opened: false,
      sortResult: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function() {
      this.opened = !this.opened
    },
    makeSelection: function(selected) {
      this.selected = selected
      this.opened = false
    },
    emitSort(option) {
      this.sortResult = option
      EventBus.$emit('sort-catagories', this.sortResult)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can't you just sort the items inside the computation of `filteredItems`?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Arrays have native sort and filter methods you can use.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/array/sort

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: I understand how to filter/ sort in javascript. My question is how to implement it i Vue. When I loop through ````<CountdownCardv-for="(event, index) in filteredItems":key="index":event="event"/>```` in the template I am only able to specify one array. What I am looking for is to both filter and sort the array concurrently.